# Streaming using camel JMS

Tags: apache-camel, jms, hornetq, fuseesb

I have a application which places message in JMS Queue.The message size can be upto 150 mb. JMS message contains byte array data with additional metadata as xml,once the message is placed in queue the camel route application picks the message and calls the external java api with the message.i would like to stream the message from the JMS Queue using camel jms component.
Can you please tell me if i can achieve it using camel.
Currently i am facing heap error issue.

Sample JMS message is as below.

```
<request>
    <esb-metadata>
        <source-transaction-id>1234567890</source-transaction-id>
        <environment>Dev</environment>
        <message-type>REQ</message-type>
        <source-id>12345678</source-id>
        <master-id>mst-id1234</master-id>
    </esb-metadata>
    <message-body>
        <parameters>
            <info>
                <document-class>Document</document-class>
                
                <document-guid>idd_C0A5DF59-0000-C51C-BCDA-E76E9476D5C2</document-guid>
            </info>
        </parameters>   
        <document>
            <document-mime-type>std/text</document-mime-type>
            <document-content>SGVhZGluZzEgQ2hhbmdlZCB0b2RheSBKYW4gMTEgc2FtcGxlIHRleHQgYmVsb3csDQpPbmNlIEkg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        </document-content>
        </document>
    </message-body>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

HornetQ has support for streaming large messages so that clients don't have to worry about hitting memory limits.  This support works in the HornetQ JMS implementation, but the JMS API doesn't directly support streaming large messages so a standard JMS component (e.g. one that Camel provides) likely won't work for this use-case.  You'd need to use a component written to support the HornetQ implementation specifically.  You can read about how HornetQ JMS clients can stream large messages in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/large-messages.html#large-messages.streaming.over.jms).