# How to send large files to ActiveMQ using camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, inputstream, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to send a X?-GB large file as a stream to an ActiveMQ queue for processing.

I know ActiveMQ [supports streams](http://activemq.apache.org/jms-streams.html), and so does [camel-jms](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html), but nothing I try to set on the queue seems to make any difference. The only thing that changes is turning off stream caching results is a "stream closed" exception instead.

I am open to using a processor or custom class (as long as resources get cleaned up), but this should be possible from the blueprint. How do I properly process a large file through camel-activemq without getting an OutOfMemoryError?

Using

- servicemix-7.0.0
- camel-2.16.4
- activemq-5.14.3

Here is my camel blueprint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"

    <!-- just calls exchange.setBody(exchange.getBody(InputStream.class)) -->    
    <bean id="toStreamBody" class="my.test.toInputStream"/>

    <!-- define a bean of type StreamCachingStrategy which CamelContext will automaticly use -->
    <bean id="streamStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy">
        <property name="spoolDirectory" value="${java.io.tmpdir}TestTemp/#uuid#/"/>
        <property name="spoolThreshold" value="131072"/>
        <property name="spoolUsedHeapMemoryThreshold" value="70"/>
        <property name="anySpoolRules" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- streamCaching="true" is "not a valid attribute" -->
    <camelContext streamCache="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <route id="file_route">
            <from uri="file://FileUploadBin?delete=false&amp;moveFailed=.error"/>
            <!-- just calls exchange.setBody(exchange.getBody(InputStream.class)) -->
            <bean ref="toStreamBody"/>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:TestQ"/>
        </route>

        <route id="myTestQ">
            <from uri="activemq:queue:TestQ?concurrentConsumers=1&amp;maxConcurrentConsumers=64&amp;maxMessagesPerTask=100&amp;asyncConsumer=true&amp;jmsMessageType=Stream&amp;mapJmsMessage=false"/>
            <bean ref="toStreamBody"/>
            <log message="FINISHED" loggingLevel="WARN"/>
        </route>

    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Here is the error I keep getting

```
2017-10-17 08:46:53,859 | ERROR |  - RecipientList | DefaultErrorHandler              | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-H2O66PO-62468-1508242908251-4-4 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-H2O66PO-62468-1508242908251-4-5). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: byte[] with value [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache] due java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[file_route        ] [file_route        ] [file://FileUploadBin?delete=false&moveFailed=.error                           ] [      3764]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
        Id                  ID-DESKTOP-H2O66PO-62468-1508242908251-4-5
        ExchangePattern     InOnly
        Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-DESKTOP-H2O66PO-62468-1508242908251-4-4, fileName=Die.txt}
        BodyType            org.apache.camel.converter.stream.FileInputStreamCache
        Body                [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: byte[] with value [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache] due java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:610)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:137)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiTypeConverter.convertTo(OsgiTypeConverter.java:108)[40:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createJmsMessageForType(JmsBinding.java:560)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:490)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.makeJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:303)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer$2.createMessage(JmsProducer.java:300)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:483)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.access$100(JmsConfiguration.java:426)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate$1.doInJms(JmsConfiguration.java:440)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:437)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:413)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:367)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:153)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:823)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:84)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:319)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:304)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1652)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:1247)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.StaticMethodTypeConverter.convertTo(StaticMethodTypeConverter.java:59)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:293)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:120)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)[:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToArbitraryChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:567)[:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:616)[:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.FileInputStreamCache.writeTo(FileInputStreamCache.java:108)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.StreamCacheConverter.convertToByteArray(StreamCacheConverter.java:102)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:1243)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.StaticMethodTypeConverter.convertTo(StaticMethodTypeConverter.java:59)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:293)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:120)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiTypeConverter.convertTo(OsgiTypeConverter.java:108)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createJmsMessageForType(JmsBinding.java:560)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:490)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.makeJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:303)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer$2.createMessage(JmsProducer.java:300)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:483)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.access$100(JmsConfiguration.java:426)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate$1.doInJms(JmsConfiguration.java:440)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:437)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:413)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:367)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:153)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
2017-10-17 08:46:57,641 | WARN  | ://FileUploadBin | GenericFileOnCompletion          | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@294a3d48 for file: GenericFile[Die.txt]
```

Comment: Related to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422970/streaming-using-camel-jms). But no answers, I'm not using hornet/fuse, and the question is unhelpful.

Comment: Have you tried camel-stream? http://camel.apache.org/stream.html. Just Replace the file component with "stream:file?fileName=fileName.in" and send directly to the queue.

Comment: @Itsallas The stream component isn't working any better.

Comment: I'm interested in this myself. I'm not sure that Camel streams are integrated with ActiveMQ streams -- broadly Camel just does standard JMS stuff. So if Camel determines that your message body needs (say) a TextMessage, it will accumulate data in the JVM heap to compose that message. I believe the "approved" way to do this stuff is to use off-line storage, and just pass references in JMS messages to the storage identifier or URI. The use of the ActiveMQ BlobMessage gives a little bit of support for this but (a) it's again not really integrated into Camel and (b) you still have to do the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really supported on the classic ActiveMQ broker.

However the next generation ActiveMQ Artemis supports large messages, and we have just added support for this in camel-jms as well. I wrote a blog entry about this: http://www.davsclaus.com/2017/10/working-with-large-messages-using.html

And we also added support for the `javax.jms.StreamMessage` type in camel-jms. However this API is not as ideal for large messages, so it has limited usage. But nevertheless you can turn it on, on the component with the new option `streamMessageTypeEnabled` in Camel 2.21 onwards, and then if the message body is streaming type then Camel will send as `StreamMessage` instead of `BytesMessage`.